# using puppet to format a disk/volume

Tags: linux, puppet, openstack

When I provision a new virtual machine with centos6, it does most of the configuration through puppet. But I have to manually run the command `#mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdc` to format `/dev/vdc`. Is there any way to automate this task in puppet as well?

Comment: Take a look at Kickstart. It should be a better option for what you are trying to do - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/3Cu-6VSVQDE

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
exec {'/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/vdc':
  unless => '/sbin/blkid -t TYPE=ext4 /dev/vdc'
}
```

The `blkid` looks for partitions of `TYPE` `ext4` in the listed devices (namely, `/dev/vdc`). If it fails, it returns a non-zero exit code, and Puppet will run the command.