# How to use puppet to format a partition with a file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, puppet

With a filesystem such as ext4 or xfs.

But how can we make sure it doesn't do it again and again on each run. I want it to do just on the `First Run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can touch a hidden  file, eg`.filename`, after formatting the filesystem and use the `unless` parameter of exec, `cat .filename` in your `unless` parameter. If the file exists, the exec won't run. Explained [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec).
Something like this :

```
exec { "/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdxx && mount /dev/sdxx /mnt/sdxx && touch /mnt/sdxx/.filename":
            unless => "cat /mnt/sdxx/.filename"
        }
```

My example might code contain errors as I am not proficient and haven't tested it.

Comment: You can use 'creates => /.file' in your exec instead of 'unless'

Comment: Rather than creating a file, you can look in the list of block devices using `blkid`, as explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251910/using-puppet-to-format-a-disk-volume:  `unless => '/sbin/blkid -t TYPE=ext4 /dev/sdxx'`

Comment: @Peter Westlake how does that answer the question of OP ? he wants to format the disk only on the first run of puppet, so the command must be executed once in the lifetime of the operating system.

Comment: It only runs the disk formatting command once. After that, the blkid command finds it, returns 0, and prevents the formatting command from being run a second time.

Comment: @Peter Westlake +1, yes much better solution. I should read the man pages before replying :D